# Groupby and assign unique IDs to group members

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange'], 
                   'distance': [10, 0, 20, 40, 20, 50 ,70, 90, 110, 130]})
df

fruit   distance
0   apple   10
1   apple   0
2   apple   20
3   apple   40
4   orange  20
5   orange  50
6   orange  70
7   orange  90
8   orange  110
9   orange  130
```

I would like to add a unique ID to each group member sorted by distance, like this:

```
    fruit   distance    ID
0   apple   10  apple_2
1   apple   0   apple_1
2   apple   20  apple_3
3   apple   40  apple_4
4   orange  20  orange_1
5   orange  50  orange_2
6   orange  70  orange_3
7   orange  130 orange_6
8   orange  110 orange_5
9   orange  90  orange_4
```

My efforts to sort/groupby/loop have not yet been successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['ID'] = df['fruit'] + "_" + df.groupby("fruit")["distance"].rank().astype(int).astype(str)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    fruit  distance        ID
0   apple        10   apple_2
1   apple         0   apple_1
2   apple        20   apple_3
3   apple        40   apple_4
4  orange        20  orange_1
5  orange        50  orange_2
6  orange        70  orange_3
7  orange        90  orange_4
8  orange       110  orange_5
9  orange       130  orange_6
```

Comment: I was close to the same as you. `df['id'] = (df['fruit'].str.cat(df.groupby('fruit')['distance'].rank().astype(int).astype(str),'_'))`  +1

Comment: Nice solution ! It's worth noting that, in case of items at the same distance, the default ranking method ('average') does not ensure the unicity (nor continuity) of ids, unlike the method 'first' which is safer then.

Comment: That's right, `rank(method='first')` is safer to ensure all IDs are unique

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

`sort` followed by `groupby` and `cumsum` and string concatenation.

I'm not sure of your sort at the end ? - but this should work.

```
nums = (df.sort_values(["fruit", "distance"]).groupby(["fruit"]).cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

df['ID'] = df['fruit'] + '_' + nums
print(df)
        fruit  distance    ID
0   apple        10   apple_2
1   apple         0   apple_1
2   apple        20   apple_3
3   apple        40   apple_4
4  orange        20  orange_1
5  orange        50  orange_2
6  orange        70  orange_3
7  orange        90  orange_4
8  orange       110  orange_5
9  orange       130  orange_6
```